# Does data save once you leave an activity android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I have an application that populates a `ListView` with user input data from another `Activity` ; however, whenever I enter that data into the second `Activity` then return to the `ListView` activity I see it populated with the values I entered. But, if I return to the second activity again, enter the values, and go back to the `ListView` activity, I see the new values updated but the old ones have disappeared. 
Now, I don't know if I'm not updating the listview correctly or if I need to use sqlite databases to store this data or shared preferences in order to update the listview to new data while containing the previous information.

Thanks for any help.

### ListActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.personalproject.peter.timerapp.TestingForAlarmData.TestAlarm;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ListOfAlarms extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int RESULT = 1000;

    List<TestAlarm> alarms = new ArrayList<>();
    String title;
    int totalTime;

 ListView listOfAlarms;
    ArrayAdapter<TestAlarm> alarmArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_alarms);



       final TextView emptyViewForList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emptyTextViewForList);

       listOfAlarms = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     alarmArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alarms);
       listOfAlarms.setAdapter(alarmArrayAdapter);

//        if(listOfAlarms.getCount() <= 0){
//            emptyViewForList.setText("No Alarms Currently Available");
//            listOfAlarms.setEmptyView(emptyViewForList);
//        }

        listOfAlarms.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               alarms.get(position);

                Intent clockDownActivity = new Intent(ListOfAlarms.this, CountDownAct.class);
               clockDownActivity.putExtra("Title", title);
               clockDownActivity.putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
                startActivity(clockDownActivity);
           }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_of_alarms, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void goToFillOut(View view) {

            Intent goingToFillOut = new Intent(this, Test.class);
            startActivityForResult(goingToFillOut, RESULT);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){


               title = data.getStringExtra("title");
                totalTime = data.getIntExtra("totalTime", 0);

                alarms.add(new TestAlarm(title, totalTime));

               alarmArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }


}
```

### SecondActivity

```
        import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Test extends ActionBarActivity {
       private static final String LOGTAG = "Test.class";
    private static final long timeInterval = 1000;


    private Button complete;
    private EditText titleEditText;
    private EditText hourEditText;
    private EditText minuteEditText;
    private EditText secondEditText;
    public static   int hour;



    public static int minute;
    public static int second;
    public static String title;




    public int actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        hourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourEditText);
        minuteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minuteEditText);
        secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);

        complete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.completeButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void saveTimer(View view) {

        if(titleEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || hourEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()
                || minuteEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty() || secondEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you forgot one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }
//            complete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            title = titleEditText.getText().toString();
            hour = Integer.parseInt(hourEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            second = Integer.parseInt(secondEditText.getText().toString().trim());

            hour *= 3600000;
            minute *= 60000;
            second *= 1000;

        actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds = hour + minute + second;


        Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, ListOfAlarms.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("totalTime", actualTimeFiniliazedInMilliSeconds);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();

    }



}
```

### Alarm.java

```
    public class TestAlarm {

public String title;
public int totalTime;

public TestAlarm (String title, int totalTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.totalTime = totalTime;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

}

Comment: please add some code so we can help with that

Comment: That depends but it's not something you should depend on. You could create a singleton to hold the data (accessible from all activities) and serialize as needed.

Comment: By default the data should not have been saved . Check if you are passing the data via intents between your activities or populating them via sharedpreferences ?

Comment: @KinnarVasa I have attached the code block.

Comment: @Don'tWasteYourTime   I have attached the code block.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 I have attached the code block.

Comment: @NileshJarad I have attached the code block

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are replacing new list in listview rather to updating old list of listview.

When you come first time on activity A, you should create one global array list where you add all items which are added by user.
Now, when user go on Activity B and add any item, you should carry out value back to Activity A and add that item in list.

After adding that in list, you should notify data to Adapter. So, here your list will have 2 items and it will show on Activity A 2 items.